# C Using char* in fscanf causing error Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c

I am new to C and I came across an issue when using `fscanf` to read all strings from a .txt file.

The code is as follow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *spIn;
    char *numIn;

    spIn = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (spIn == NULL) {
        printf("Can't Open This File \n");
    }

    while ((fscanf(spIn, "%s", numIn)) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", numIn);
    };

    fclose(spIn);
    return 1;
}
```

This throws an error: `Segmentation fault: 11`.

The original data on txt file is:

```
1 2 345 rrtts46
dfddcd gh 21
789 kl
```

a mix of ints, strings, white space and newline characters.

Answer (score 4):

At least 4 candidate undefined behaviors (UB) that could lead to a fault of some kind.

1. Code fails to pass to `fscanf(spIn,"%s",numIn)` an initialized pointer.
2. Code calls `fscanf()` even if `fopen()` fails.
3. Code calls `fclose()` even if `fopen()` fails.
4. No width limit in `fscanf(spIn,"%s",numIn))`, worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

---

Text files really do not have *strings* (`'\0'` terminated data) nor `int`, they have *lines* (various characters with a `'\n'` termination).

To read a *line* in and save as a *string*, use `fgets()`.  Do not use `fscanf()` to read lines of data.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *spIn = fopen("data.txt", "r");
  if (spIn == NULL) {
    printf("Can't Open This File \n");
  } else {
    char buf[100];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, spIn)) {
      printf("%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(spIn);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `%s` "worse" than `gets`? I understand why it is "as bad as" `gets`, but I don't understand why it is supposed to be "worse" than `gets`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `gets()` at least reads the entire _line_, `'\n'` included. `fscanf(spIn,"%s",numIn)` only reads `"dfddcd"` and not `"dfddcd gh 21"` nor `"dfddcd gh 21\n"`.  OP (and many others) conflate `"%s"` (reading a _string_, it does not) with reading a _line_.  At least `gets()` is dropped in C11 so easier to find bad `gets()` code than bad `fscanf(spIn,"%s",numIn)`.

Comment: There was an attempt in C11 to sanitize `scanf` and other string functions in Annex K: too bad the error handling scheme was such a contraption. One can use `grep -n '%s' *.c | grep 'scanf'` to try and locate *bad* calls.

Comment: @chqrlie 2 alternatives I hope C does, 1) with `*scanf()`  or variant, provide passing a `size_t` parameter with `%s, %[` 2) Provide an efficient  `size_t readline(size_t, char *buf, FILE *)` to read an entire line, save what it can and return length saved.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `readline` should also discard the newline to act as a replacement for `gets()`. I would use `size_t readline(char *, size_t, FILE *)` for consistency with other standard functions taking a buffer and its length. Similarly `size_t sstrcpy(char *dest, size_t n, const char *src)` would act like `snprintf(dest, n, "%s", src)` and return the length of `src`...

Comment: Perhaps we could design a good functional interface someday?  Consider `size_t` first per [a new principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).  Note `sprintf()` returns `int`.

Answer (score 3):

`char* numIn` is a pointer, and it is uninitalized, you can't really store anything in it, you need to either allocate memory for it or make it point to some valid memory location:

```
#include<stdlib.h> // for malloc

char* numIn = malloc(100); // space for 99 char + null terminator byte    
//...
while ((fscanf(spIn, "%99s", numIn)) == 1)
{
    printf("%s\n",numIn);
};
```

Or:

```
char str[100];
char *numIn = str;
```

Which in this small code makes little sense, you should probably make `numIn` a fixed size array to begin with:

```
char numIn[100];
```

Note that that you should use a width specifier in `*scanf` to avoid buffer overflow. This still has a problem though, it will read word by word, instead of line by line.

Looking at your input file, using `fgets` seems like a better option, it can read complete lines, including spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *spIn;
    char numIn[100];
    spIn = fopen("data.txt", "r");

    if (spIn != NULL)
    {
        while ((fgets(numIn, sizeof numIn, spIn)))
        {
            numIn[strcspn(numIn, "\n")] = '\0'; // removing \n
            printf("%s\n", numIn);
        }
        fclose(spIn);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Can't Open This File");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Since `fgets` also parses the `\n` character, I'm removing it with `strcspn`.

Though you do verify the return value of `fopen` the execution continues even if it fails to open, I also addressed that issue.